# Having Trouble with a 2D Array in java

Tags: java, arrays

fairly new here and fairly new to java. Passed my programming 1 course with and A last spring and now I am here in Programming 2 and I'm finally struggling. Normally I don't ask for help, and please if you do decide to help, don't hold my hand. I am mainly looking for some one to talk me through this assignment. 
So the assignment must:

- a. Declares an appropriate data structure to hold such sky image.
- b. Reads the data file “sky image.txt” into the data structure.
- c. A method called “lightSource” that receives the sky image data and returns the location of the brightest interior spot as a point. Use Java.awt.Point to represent a point.
- d. A method called “darkSource” that receives the sky image data and returns the location of the darkest interior spot as a point. Use Java.awt.Point to represent a point.
- e. A method that displays the sky image data.
- f. A method called “filterImage” that receives the image data and an integer. The method then adds the integer to all the values while keeping the values within 0 and 1024. This method will be used to over-expose (brighten) or under-expose (darken) an image. Overexposing is when you add a positive value to all the grid values. Under-exposing when you add a negative value to all the grid values.
- g. A method called negativeImage that produces the “negative” of the image. To produce the negative, replace any value x with its complement 1024 – x

Now the problem I am having is, I created the 2D array read the file and filled it, I am just unsure how to proceed. I dont want any of you to hand me the answer or whats the point. Any ideas on how to proceed would be fantastic as I have just been thowing ideas around all day, none of which seem to be working to my liking

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Create2DArray {
    public static int[][] array;
    public static int dimension1, dimension2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            File inputFile = new File("sky image.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);
            dimension1 = scan.nextInt();
            dimension2 = scan.nextInt();
            array = new int[dimension1][dimension2];
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                for (int row = 0; row < dimension1; row++) {
                    for (int column = 0; column < dimension2; column++) {
                        array[row][column] = scan.nextInt();
                        System.out.printf("%4d ", array[row][column]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }
            scan.close();
        }


}
```

Comment: well, some of it tells you exactly what to do.  for example, "c. a method called lightsource that recieves the sky image data and returns...as a point" .  so you need to create a method in your class, like `public static java.awt.Point lightSource( int[][] imageData )` and then implement what it says to do, then repeat those instructions for each of the other steps.  which **specific** part of your list are you having problems with?

Comment: well I cant seem to figure out how to get the the whole thing to come together nicely, I having trouble seeing past creating the 2D array, initializing and filling her with the data from the file. Once thats done, as you can see from my code, I am unsure in how to proceeed with creating the apporiate methods to manipulate the array. See what Im saying. For some reason my mind shifts my code over to creating the array using a constructor like this

Comment: public Create2DArray(int[][] array, int dimension1, int dimension2, Point p) throws FileNotFoundException

Comment: and then filling adding the code i aldready have for creating the array

Comment: basically im lost :0

Comment: Are you supposed to be doing this in an object oriented fashion? If so, creating an object would be a good thing to do. After that, as @JohnGardner mentioned, since you know you need some methods, make the methods. Then come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom yes its object oriented programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without doing ALL of the work, here's a starting point:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Homework {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {       
        // run through the homework

        // read the data (b)
        int[][] array = loadData("sky image.txt");

        // (c) lightSource
        Point light = lightSource(array);
        // check the answer here, is it right?

        // (d) darkSource

        // ... calls, checks for e-g here.

    }

    /** b. Reads the data file “sky image.txt” into the data structure. */
    public static int[][] loadData(string fileName) {
        // your code that is already in main, didn't re-write it just moved it
        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);
        int dimension1 = scan.nextInt();
        int dimension2 = scan.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[dimension1][dimension2];
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            for (int row = 0; row < dimension1; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < dimension2; column++) {
                    array[row][column] = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.printf("%4d ", array[row][column]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
        sc.close();

        return array;
    }

    /** 
     * c. A method called “lightSource” that receives the sky image data and returns the location of the brightest interior spot as a point. 
     * Use Java.awt.Point to represent a point. 
     */
    public static java.awt.Point lightSource( int[][] imageData ) {
        // write code here
        return new java.awt.Point( 0, 0 );
    }


    // put more methods here
}
```

Comment: it doesn't probably compile, i just typed it in notepad++, but should give you a starting point?

Comment: also, step (a) was "determine an appropriate data structure".  it was implied in your work above that your answer to that was "a 2d int array is an appropriate data structure".  i'm not answering that for you here either.  depending on what kind of class this is (OO?  data structures?) the answer might be different.

Comment: hes looking for a 2D array, he wanted us to figure that out which was obvious from the start. The class is programming 2 using Java. Without specifying the size of the array, you read the first to lines of the file which are 20 and 25 and this give you the dimensions of the array. So you have 20 rows and 25 columns with integers from 0 to 1024. 0 is darkest and 1024 is brightest.

Comment: Now the methods lightsource and dark source should read the array and returns the coordinates of the brightest are darkest spot. A method to return the image data and then a method to filter the data to either "brighten" or "darken" the image. Then create a method to produce a negative of that image. You have pretty much answer my question tho now I just have to think about it, thanks for the direction. I find programming to be easier to learn if i could just talk through it with someone

Comment: also dont think my orginal code complied for you because A) sc.close(); should be scan.close(); and B) you obviously dont have the text file im working with

Comment: Sure, ok, it's a start. But definitely not OO, which OP indicates he wants.

Comment: yes, hence my second comment, "i'm not answering [(a)] for you here either".  in fact, the easiest way to do that would probably just search for the string "int[][]" and replace it with "AppropriateDataStructure" above, and then do that work.